# Error node: error: bind message supplies 16 parameters, but prepared statement "" requires 15

Tags: node.js, pg

Why I get this error:

```
error: bind message supplies 16 parameters, but prepared statement "" requires 15
```

code:

```
    const r1 = await client.query(`
        INSERT INTO booking 
          (client_id, car_id, business_id, pick_up_station_id, 
            return_station_id, type, text, from_date, to_date, booking_range, km_free, km_extra, km_overdrawn, excess_back)
          VALUES
          ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9, tsrange($10, $11, '()'), $12, $13, $14, $15) RETURNING ID;
    `, [
        p.client_id !== '' ? parseInt(p.client_id) : null, 
        parseInt(p.car_id), parseInt(p.business_id), 
        parseInt(p.business_id),
        p.pick_up_station_id, 
        p.return_station_id, 
        p.type, 
        p.notice, 
        new Date(p.date_from),
        new Date(p.date_to),
        new Date(p.date_from),
        new Date(p.date_to),
        parseInt(p.free_km),
        parseInt(p.extra_km),
        0,
        0
      ]);
```

What I am doing wrong ? Maybe this error comes because the tsrange but idk how to solve it

can anyone help me to solve this issue

thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is pretty clear. Your statement requires 15 parameters, but you pass 16. You added `parseInt(p.business_id)` twice. It should be:

```
[
  p.client_id !== '' ? parseInt(p.client_id) : null,
  parseInt(p.car_id), // Removed parseInt(p.business_id)
  parseInt(p.business_id),
  p.pick_up_station_id,
  p.return_station_id,
  p.type,
  p.notice,
  new Date(p.date_from),
  new Date(p.date_to),
  new Date(p.date_from),
  new Date(p.date_to),
  parseInt(p.free_km),
  parseInt(p.extra_km),
  0,
  0
]
```

Comment: omg I didnt see the twice p.business_id thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Try combining the date_from and date_to values into a single range value before passing it to the query.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).